# py2exe, option=windows, how to prompts warning msg in command-line mode if input wrong sys.args ?

Tags: python, wxpython, py2exe

I have a GUI program using wxpython, and I build it as an exe file by py2exe with option=windows
that I do not want to show a console window behind my GUI program

and also it allows to use sys.args to do some silent stuffs without GUI windows.
But it does not prompt any warning msg if I input wrong invalid args

Does anyone know how to solve my question ?

Thank you for any help

Morris

Comment: I have a rough idea that detect len(sys.args) > 1  means user  inputs some args in command console.
App_w.exe(option=windows) generates a bat file then call the bat file and then close App_w.exe itself.
The bat file call App_c.exe(option=console). I think msg will show on the same console widow.
That means I have to build twice exe, App_w.exe and App_c.exe, in my app folder, user can see App_w.exe and App_c.exe.
I have seen the same solution, I did not understand why at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You can `wxPython` have redirect `STOUT/STDERR`. In creating your app, just do:

```
app = wx.App(redirect=True) # 0 is the default value
```

and `STDOUT/STDERR` will go to a separate frame and not to the console. You can even check `hasattr(sys, 'frozen')` to switch behaviour only when frozen.

Comment: Thanks your reply, as you said it popups a new wxpython STDOUT frame.  But it looks ugly  [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/2hzpgeb.jpg[/IMG] Do you have any idea to redirect msg to original command console?

Comment: This seems to be a rather involved process and I have no experience in it. I would suggest to use proper logging anyway as soon as your app gets a little bit more involved (see python logging).